# Conditional __debug__ statement not executed though __debug__ is True

Tags: python, debugging, iis-7, python-ldap

**Short Version**

I have a section of code I'm debugging that checks the value of `__debug__` and executes some code if it is True.

```
if __debug__:
  <stuff happens>
```

The problem is that "stuff" never happens, even though `__debug__` appears to be True.

**Long Version / Details**

To check this, I am printing out the values of several variables, most notably `__debug__`, to a file as the function executes, using the following pattern.  (I am using `os.open` because `open` is already defined in this module.)

```
try:
  myfile = os.open("test.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT|os.O_APPEND)
  # work + some print statements to check the value of __DEBUG__
finally:
  os.close(myfile)
```

The piece of code I'm most confused by looks like this:

```
os.write(myfile, "LINE %s | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: %s \n" %(sys._getframe(0).f_lineno, __debug__))
os.write(myfile, "LINE %s | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: %s \n" %(sys._getframe(0).f_lineno, type(__debug__)))
os.write(myfile, "LINE %s | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: %s \n" %(sys._getframe(0).f_lineno, bool(__debug__)))
if __debug__:
  os.write(myfile, "LINE %s | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: %s \n" %(sys._getframe(0).f_lineno, __debug__))
if bool(__debug__):
  os.write(myfile, "LINE %s | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: %s \n" %(sys._getframe(0).f_lineno, __debug__))
if True:
  os.write(myfile, "LINE %s | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: %s \n" %(sys._getframe(0).f_lineno, __debug__))
if __debug__:
  os.write(myfile, "LINE %s | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: %s \n" %(sys._getframe(0).f_lineno, __debug__))
```

And the output file looks like this:

```
LINE 82 | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: True 
LINE 83 | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: <type 'bool'> 
LINE 84 | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: True 
LINE 88 | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: True 
LINE 90 | LDAP FUNCTION __DEBUG__: True
```

The first 3 statements (lines 82-84) are every way I could think of checking if `__debug__` is "truthy", and all 3 imply that `__debug__` is True.  Similarly, casting `__debug__` as a boolean and then evaluating `if` (line 88) works as expected too.  Line 90 is a silly sanity check.

Is there anything I'm missing in the way `__debug__` works that may be causing this?

*Note*: I found this while I was working through an error I am getting in the `_ldap_function_call` function in the `python-ldap` module.  I only get this error when using IIS - everything works fine with Django's development server.

Comment: What version of Python is this? In 2.7 and 3.x, assigning to `__debug__` is a `SyntaxError`; in earlier 2.x versions `__debug__` wasn't a magic constant—but in 2.6, and a few versions before that (not sure how many), it is a magic constant, but you can rebind the name to something else, which leads to weirdness.

Comment: Maybe it's caused by something strange: I suspect .pyc/.pyo files.  Does removing any .pyc/.pyo file help solve the problem?

Comment: @abarnert: Ah.  But the weirdness is still possible: http://bpaste.net/show/82378/ .  turtlemonvh: either your code mangle `__debug__` in this way, or more likely, the context code does (python-ldap?).

Comment: @ArminRigo: Ah, I was thinking more about `sys.modules[__name__].__debug__`, which is legal in 2.6 but not 2.7, and can cause symptoms exactly like what he's seeing. But you're right, `globals()['__debug__']` still works in 2.7, and it might cause the same problems. Let me check.

Comment: @abarnert The python version is 2.7.

Comment: @ArminRigo I'm going to give deleting the *.pyc/*.pyo files a try and see what comes of that.  Thank you both for the suggestions!

Comment: I checked the `ldap` and `django-ldap` directories, and neither seems to reassign `__debug__`.  I also deleted all .pyc/.pyo files in `ldap`, but I'm still getting the same behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you rebind `__debug__`, it can cause symptoms exactly like this.

This is because `__debug__` is somewhat magical. During module compilation, the same code that handles literals also handles the magic constants `...`, `None`, `True`, `False`, and `__debug__`. (See, for example, [`expr_constant`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/compile.c#l3184).)

If you run `dis` on your code to dump out the bytecode, you'll see that `if __debug__:` statements are either removed entirely, or use `LOAD_CONST` to load the compile-time `debug` constant, while `if bool(__debug__):` statements use `LOAD_GLOBAL` to load the value of `__debug__`.

Of course these are guaranteed to be the same… unless you rebind `__debug__`. Somewhere around 2.3, it became illegal to just write `__debug__ = False`. In 2.7 and 3.0, it became illegal to bind *any* attribute named `__debug__`, which means you can no longer do things like `sys.modules[__name__].__debug__ = False`. But you can still do, e.g., `globals()['__debug__'] = False`.

And either way, you get the same effect:

```
if __debug__:
    print "debug"
if bool(__debug__):
    print "bool"

import sys
sys.modules[__name__].__debug__ = False

if __debug__:
    print "debug2"
if bool(__debug__):
    print "bool2"
```

This prints out:

```
debug
bool
debug2
```

And likewise for code that sets it to True when run with `python -O`.

Comment: In 2.6-3.3, any rich comparison to `__debug__` will also trigger `LOAD_NAME` (in a module/class) or `LOAD_GLOBAL` (in a function). If you're running without `-O`, then the suite for `if __debug__` is inlined; otherwise it's omitted. I didn't see a `LOAD_CONST` used to test the debug state in any of my tests. Which Python version compiles it to `co_consts`?

Comment: @abarnert This sound like solid logic to me.  I didn't find any place in the ldap-related modules where `__debug__` was modified, but I think that the [PyISAPIe library](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyisapie) I'm using to run django on IIS may be part of the issue.

Comment: @abarnet A related question - because of the pre-processing step, `if __debug__ and True:` != `if __debug__:`, right?  I originally found this anomaly by breaking up `and`ed if statements into multiple statements and noticing this changed what errors I was getting.  I'm guessing these are the same phenomena.

Comment: @turtlemonvh: The only way to be sure is to test. So, write `def foo(): if __debug__ and True: pass` and `def bar(): if __debug__: pass` and `dis.dis` each one. The first does `LOAD_GLOBAL` then `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` on each constant; the second just removes the comparison entirely (as eryksun pointed out). So yes, your guess is correct.

Comment: @eryksun: I didn't test every version or read all of the relevant source, so I didn't want to say categorically that it always omits the test in every version. Even if there were a version that didn't omit the test, it would still be treated as a magic immutable literal, which means that assigning to `__debug__` would still lead to inconsistent behavior in different statements, exactly like the OP is seeing. But thanks for testing all 6 versions!

Comment: Actually I didn't test 3.0 and 3.1, but I did check [`expr_constant`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7395330e495e/Python/compile.c#l3020) in the 3.1.5 source (that's a tag link, so it should be rteliable). If it kept the test and ran the suite, then the OP would have output for lines 86 and 92, since `__debug__` is true -- unless there's a version that compiles a `__debug__` boolean constant into the code object. It seems silly, but you never know, which is why I asked.